# python matplotlib - dynamical plot with errorbars?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to have a script where the plot is interactively updated. I can do this for regular plots.

The main code is, that a plot object is assigned into a variable, and this can than be set to whatever one wants. Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
test, = ax.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
test.set_ydata([7,8,9])
```

This works nicely. But this does not work if I use `.errorbar()` instead of `.plot()`.

The syntax for errorbar is `ax.errorbar(x,y,error)`, but `test,=ax.errorbar([1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3])` gives me a "too many values to unpack" error.

Do you know how I can make this happen?
Thx.

Comment: Which version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: I am using 1.5.1